# Meteor: Accounts.createUser throws exception: meteor.roles.$name_1 dup key

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

Trying to add new users to `users` collection on registration.

On Meteor's client side, I call a server method to add the user to `users` collection

```
Meteor.methods({
    createUserServer : function (user) {

        // On server-side, Accounts.createUser is essentially
        // blocking (Fibers): it waits for the user to be
        // created, and then returns its newly generated id.
        try {
            var userId = Accounts.createUser(user)
            console.log('user ID: ' , userId);
            return { success:true , message : userId }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Meteor Exception: ',e);
            return { success : false , message : e.reason }
        }






    }
})
```

The addition happens nicely on `users` collection for the first time only, but after that, I get this exception:

`Meteor Exception:  { [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.roles.$name_1  dup key: { : null }] stack: [Getter] }`

I checked the `roles` collection on the db, I found only one document:

`db.roles.find()` --> returns --> `{ "_id" : "whef5ZW8sBchDWBuH", "userId" : "WNM7gYDusa2dJY8wd", "roles" : [ ] }`

I'm not sure what type of problem is that?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

For some reason the `name` document was made as an index and unique, which caused the above conflict, by removing that index, things work fine now:

```
Meteor.roles._ensureIndex('name', {unique: 1})
```

Now I'm happy :)

Ref: https://github.com/orionjs/orion/issues/239